# Return reference to a vector member variable

Tags: c++, vector, reference, constants

I have a vector as member in a class and I want to return a reference to it through a getVector() function, so as to be able to modify it later. Isn’t it better practice the function getVector() to be const? However I got an error “qualifiers dropped in binding reference of type…” in the following code. What should be modified?

```
class VectorHolder
{
public:
VectorHolder(const std::vector<int>&);
std::vector<int>& getVector() const;

private:
std::vector<int> myVector;

};

std::vector<int> &VectorHolder::getVector() const
{
return myVector;
}
```

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Since it is a `const` member function, the return type cannot be non-const reference. Make it `const`:

```
const std::vector<int> &VectorHolder::getVector() const
{
   return myVector;
}
```

Now it is okay.

Why is it fine? Because in a `const` member function, the every member becomes *const* in such a way that it cannot be modified, which means `myVector` is a `const` vector in the function, that is why you have to make the return type `const` as well, if it returns the *reference*.

Now you *cannot* modify the *same* object. See what you can do and what cannot:

```
 std::vector<int> & a = x.getVector();       //error - at compile time!

 const std::vector<int> & a = x.getVector(); //ok
 a.push_back(10);                            //error - at compile time!

 std::vector<int>  a = x.getVector();        //ok
 a.push_back(10);                            //ok
```

By the way, I'm wondering why you need such `VectorHolder` in the first place.

Comment: In this way is then impossible to modify the returned vector later from the code where you return it?

Answer (score 23):

it's not unusual to declare both const and mutable variants, like so:

```
std::vector<int>& VectorHolder::getVector() {
  return myVector;
}
const std::vector<int>& VectorHolder::getVector() const {
  return myVector;
}
```

the underlying problem with your program is that you return a non-const reference from a const method.

```
std::vector<int>& VectorHolder::getVector() const {
  return myVector; // << error: return mutable reference from const method
}
```

so you make it const using this form:

```
const std::vector<int>& VectorHolder::getVector() const {
  return myVector; // << ok
}
```

and when this is in a non const method or the client holds a non-const reference, then you can legally use a non-const method:

```
std::vector<int>& VectorHolder::getVector() {
  return myVector; // << ok
}
```

finally, you could return a value (in some cases):

```
std::vector<int> VectorHolder::getVector() const {
  return myVector; // << ok
}
```

because the copy requires no mutation and provides no exposure to the internal data.

so you will end up declaring both variants quite often.

the results of declaring both are:

```
VectorHolder m;
const VectorHolder c;

m.getVector().size(); // << ok
c.getVector().size(); // << ok - no mutation

m.getVector().push_back(a); // << ok
c.getVector().push_back(a); // << error: attempt to mutate const reference because the const vector is returned
```

so it all works out nicely (apart from the redundancy of the methods).

Answer (score 3):

The function `getVector` can be declared as `const`. It returns a reference that can be modified, so while the actual function doesn't modify anything in the class, the caller will be able to modify internal data.

Declare it as:

```
std::vector<int>& getVector();
```

If you want a function to return a vector that can't be modified, the use the `const` modifier on both the vector and the function:

```
const std::vector<int>& getVector() const;
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that a const member function should only return const references. This is because in a const function, every data member becomes constant.

Therefore you have to declare the getVector() this way:

```
std::vector<int> &VectorHolder::getVector() const;
```

Comment: Regardless to the above, it's, probably, not a good idea to expose your internal container. If some day you will decide to migrate from vector to a map, your users will be affected. I'd suggest to implement iterators instead.